# Creating anchors using views glossary

Tags: views

I have a list of nodes that are tagged with taxonomy terms. I have a view that groups the nodes by their terms and shows them all on one page. I know that glossary mode with an attachment is a great way to allow users to filter the content. I have added a glossary to the top, but when I click the terms it goes to the taxonomy term page instead of jumping down the page to the proper heading. Is this jumping behavior even possible with views without altering the views template?